# Automatically set multiple file types in `filetype` if a file has multiple extensions

Tags: vim

I frequently develop on Ruby on Rails. With the recent inclusion of Tilt in RoR 3, we have file extensions like `.scss.erb`. How can I make the `filetype = scss.erb` in this case automatically, and the same for every file that has multiple extensions?

Edit: It should be `scss.eruby` in this case, as `erb` extension defaults to `eruby` filetype.

Edit: If it wasn't clear, I'm looking for a way to make this work dynamically for all files with multiple extensions. For example, file `foo.js.html` should have a filetype of `js.html`.

Edit again: Prince Goulash's answer doesn't take the default filetype for a particular extension.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to always use the default type of the last part of the file extension (in this case getting `eruby` from the  `.erb` extension), but prefixed with the first part (`scss`)?

Comment: ... if so, take a look at my most recente edit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.scss.erb setlocal filetype=scss.eruby
```

(see `:help ftdetect`, section 2).

**EDIT**

To set the filetype dyanamically for multiple extensions, this seems to work for me:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.*.*
    \ sil exe "setlocal filetype=" . substitute(expand("%"),"^[^.]*\.","",1)
```

The `substitute` command constructs the filtype by simply stripping all text from the filename before the first `.`. There may be a more sophisticated way...

**EDIT AGAIN**

Here's another attempt. `MultiExtensionFiletype()` is function that uses the default filetype of the last part of the extension and prefixes it with the first part of the extension (i.e. the part sandwiched between the dots).

```
function MultiExtensionFiletype()
    let ft_default=&filetype
    let ft_prefix=substitute(matchstr(expand('%'),'\..\+\.'),'\.','','g')
    sil exe "set filetype=" . ft_prefix  . "." . ft_default
endfunction
```

The function must be called on a `BufReadPost` event so the initial filetype is set by ignoring the multiple extensions.

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.*.* call MultiExtensionFiletype()
```

Hopefully this answer is converging on something useful!

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I've updated the question.

Comment: I wondered if I was oversimplifying it! Does my edit do what you want?

Comment: There's one small (or big) problem with this. `erb` files default to `eruby` ft, with your code, it's setting erb to erb, instead of eruby.

Comment: I have added another approach, which might be closer to what you want.

Comment: Would it be a simple fix to make it expand both the extensions? It's fine this way too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To expand both extensions we would need a way to map the extension to the filetype without actually opening a file with that extension. I tried reading the results of `:au BufRead *.[ext]` to a variable, but the result is not standard (e.g. compare the results if `erb` and `htm`). There must be a way, though.